# How to Pass Id in Laravel URL Parameter

Tags: php, laravel

How to Pass `$val->id` in **Laravel URL Parameter**. I use Following Code. Its Return Error

```
href="{{url('/dashboard/medicinepending/{{$val->id}}')}}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
href="{{ URL('/dashboard/medicinepending/'.$val->id )}}"
```

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
{{ url('/dashboard/medicinepending/', [$val->id]) }}
```

But it's a bad idea to use relative paths, because if you'll want to change URL scheme, you will need to manually find tens or hundreds links in your views and controllers and change them manually. In this case you'll definitely forget to change some of them and some pages of your app will be broken.

A good practice is to use links to route:

```
{{ route('name.route', ['id' => $val->id]) }}
```

Or links to action:

```
{{ action('MyController@show', $val->id) }}
```

Comment: Actually using url is the right function because those other examples you provided eventually run through the url component.

Comment: @ash, please read that part of the answer where I'm explaining why using `url()` is a bad idea.

Comment: I have read what you said, and what you said is wrong lol. Route and action will users url :/

Comment: I did not miss the point, the point is you use `url` to build urls.  When your application uses multiple domain names/countries i.e.. *.com = US* site and *.co.uk = UK* site *.eu = EU* site *.jp = japanese* site, etc etc, your `url` component (you build yourself to override the core laravel url facade, which is returned via `url` from the Container, you know "IoC") will generate the correct urls with only 1 service provider... You're missing the point.

Comment: [See the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L616) you can clearly see: `url`, `route` and `action` *ALL* are sent through `UrlGenerator` via `app('url')`.  You're welcome

Comment: @ash, nobody says here that `route` do not use `url` or something. It's not important at all, you're missing the point here. I'm saying that it's a really bad idea to use hardcoded URLs. In real app, when you'll change one URL, you will need to manually change tens or hundreds `url()` clauses all over your app. It's a terrible practice to use hardcoded URLs in a real app. I don't know how else I can explain you this.

Comment: How often do really need to change URLs? It happens pretty often. Now, how often do you really need to change name of the route or action? I guess never. If you have enough experience in Web Development, you should know that those situations where you need to change URL schemas are really painful. And we are very happy to have modern frameworks which give us the way to avoid such problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106696/discussion-between-ash-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: Agreed with SEO, but also there are bosses who're saying you to change URLs, design&CSS or completely remake a website. Anyway, it seems we're living in parallel universes. I'm done here, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

## Quick Answer

As previously explained the way in which to build a URL within a blade template you can use the [`url` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url); for your example this would work:

```
{{ url('dashboard/medicinepending/', [$val->id] }}
```

## Best Practice

It is not advised to use `url`, `route` or even `action` when building a url for your views.  This is because the URLs will not change, if they do you should have 301 redirects set-up in order for your SEO score to remain valid and good.

So simply do something like:

```
<a href="/dashboard/medicinepending/{{ $val->id }}">
```

But if you *REALLY* want to use a wrapper then `url` is the second best thing.

The only purpose of these helpers are for e-mails or commands via `artisan`, when fired the cron does not know about the URL only what is defined in the config: [`app.url`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L42)

## Explanation

The way in which URLs are built with laravel is by prepending the string with the value of `app.url` config; found: [inside config/app.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L42)

This is mainly for the CLI, when you have cron processes running and generating e-mails from a queue with links, therefore this could be used within your application. **Otherwise do not use it at all**.

Using the `url` helper is good because you can change the value of the `app.url` config by your own [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers#writing-service-providers).  This is very useful for when you have a website in multiple languages and/or load a sites language based on the domain name; example:

- domain.com - would load the US website
- domain.uk - would load the UK website
- domain.eu - would load a generic EU website
- domain.de - would load the German website
- domain.jp - would load the Japanese website
- etc

As also mentioned you can build urls from a route; this is only valid if you name your routes which is not always the case.

```
{{ route('name.route', ['id' => $val->id] }}
```

This will find the route by the name **route.name** and then parse that end-point through `app('url')` which happens to be the [UrlGenerator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php) - so this is no better than the `url` helper - do not go out of your way to name all routes - that is bad practice.

Another practice mentioned which is also not a good idea is using `action` by providing the class and action to find a route:

```
{{ action('MyController@show', $val->id) }}
```

This is a bad idea unless `MyController` is actually an interface **NOT** a physical class, in that you need Inversion of Control to inject the class that implements **MyController** otherwise your application will not conform to the [S.O.L.I.D Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: If marketing decides to move /posts/{id} to /stories/{id} using action(...) would require one modification to the routes.php file to the new URL, and a one-line redirect for old urls. Using absolute URLs would require hundreds of edits.

Comment: @DustinGraham by using `action()` you are specifying the full namespace to the controller, which isn't a good idea when you're overriding/replacing controllers via the DI.  For an internal system that has one scope, it's all well and good avoiding IoC, but for open source projects and scalable enterprise systems this is not very good at all.

Comment: I suppose that's a good argument for using named routes. `route('vendor.target')` I don't experience either need very often, but I do think URL changes have been a more common need for me than controller replacement. It would have been nice had wordpress not hard coded the /wp-admin/ route or wp-login.php path. It would make it much easier to move it around to avoid rote pentest spam. I understand what you're saying though, and DI is valuable. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @DustinGraham I understand and also agree somewhat, I think this ultimately is a problem with the MVC pattern and using template engines.  Perhaps tit for tat, though I break code into packages (ideally framework agnostic) and then generic UI to be implemented by the App - this means the ability to override controllers (which tend to be 3 lines long max using services and repositories), sometimes replacing routes entirely and sometimes just one controller action - it's easier referring to a url I find.

Answer (score 2):

By the way,i also agree with @Alexey Mezenin, you should prefer route() helper function instead of using url(), route() will give you more flexibility to pass number of params along-with the main URL.

Anyways, you shouldn't use blade code syntax ({{}}) again inside another couple of brackets and one more thing, try to avoid starting and ending slashed in the first part of url like below.

You should update your code with the following one, this will hopefully work.

**href="{{ url('dashboard/medicinepending'.$val->id )}}"**
                   OR

**href="{{ url('dashboard/medicinepending',$val->id )}}"**

Comment: i've explained `url`, `route` and `action` ALL get parsed through `app('url')` which returns an instance of `UrlGenerator`, this allows multiple parameters without the need of escaping.

Comment: ash, I have answered to this question early in brief way just for his understanding, It's better that you have explained in detail. 
Hope @Matheshwaran can understand my point of view easily.

Answer (score 1):

This working for me:

```
<a href="{{asset('/dashboard/medicinepending/'.$val->id)}}"></a>
```

Comment: how to retrieve this id in blade view can you add answer to that too . thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any answer @JagdishSharma?