# Unable to get complete URL in Password Reset in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using the Laravel 5 ResetsPasswords trait to implement password reset. In the file  `resources/views/emails/password.blade.php.`, I have the following code.

```
<a href="{{ url('/password/reset/'.$token) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Click To Reset Password</a>
```

I am using a queue to send the email to the user. When the user clicks the link received in email, I get something like below:

```
http://localhost/password/reset/2aafe5381baa67f9d1fe2f476c0f1395b21e71fafe181b2980fb838fc9e0b2fc
```

I was rather expecting:

```
http://localhost/oap/public/password/reset/2aafe5381baa67f9d1fe2f476c0f1395b21e71fafe181b2980fb838fc9e0b2fc
```

Why is `oap/public/` not in the url? I have used the url() function in other views and they have worked just well except for this email view where I am using queue to send the message. When a queue is not used to send the message, the link is okay. Any idea how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: oap/public/* is not the generally accepted path of a laravel application. The frontend will (should) be through public with everything else hidden outside of web view so localhost/password/* is correct.

Comment: [Check out my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076237/how-to-pass-id-in-laravel-url-parameter#36082835) regarding the process of `url`.  *TL;DR it's because E-mail queue is executed via `Artisan` and the `url` helper appends your first parameter with the value from `app.url` config.*

Comment: Thanks @ash. Your answer in the other post help me to figure out a way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `URL::to`. Like,

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/password/reset/'.$token) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Click To Reset Password</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

for the url helpers it will generate the full path for your inputs

```
{{ url('/password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

will generate

```
http://localhost/password/reset/2aafe5381baa67f9d1fe2f476c0f1395b21e71fafe181b2980fb838fc9e0b2fc
```

and

```
{{ url('/oap/public/password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

will generate

```
http://localhost/oap/public/password/reset/2aafe5381baa67f9d1fe2f476c0f1395b21e71fafe181b2980fb838fc9e0b2fc
```

you can also get around this

```
Route::get('oap/public/password/reset/{confirmcode}', ['as' => 'resetpassword', 'HomeController@resetmethod']);
```

then using this like that

```
{{route('resetpassword', ['confirmcode' => $token])}}
```