# Why the code works on the first template but does not work on the second template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have simple routes group in my `web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'inbox', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'InboxController@inbox',])->name('inbox');
    Route::get('/message/{id?}', 'InboxController@message')->name('message');
    Route::get('/read/{id?}', 'InboxController@read')->name('read');    
});
```

And I have view:

```
<a href="{{ route('read'). '/' .$message->id }}">
    <div class="letter-icon-title text-default">{{$message->messageSender->name}}</div>
</a>
```

And here code of my `read()` method:

```
public function read(Request $request, $id)
{
    $getMessage   = Inbox::where('id', $id)->get();

    $user_id      = Auth::user()->id;
    $sender_id    = $getMessage->first()->sender;
    $recipient_id = $getMessage->first()->recipient;
    $seen         = $getMessage->first()->seen;

    $data = $this->getMessage($id);

    return view("layouts/inbox/theme-limitless/message", $data, $this->countMessages());
}
```

And my method `getMessage()` code:

```
public function getMessage($id)
{
    $getMessage      = Inbox::where('id', $id)->get();

    $date            = $getMessage->first()->created_at;
    $status          = $getMessage->first()->seen;
    $subject         = $getMessage->first()->subject;
    $message         = $getMessage->first()->message;

    $user_id         = Auth::user()->id;
    $sender_id       = $getMessage->first()->sender;
    $message_id      = $getMessage->first()->id;
    $recipient_id    = $getMessage->first()->recipient;

    $sender          = $getMessage->first()->messageSender->name;
    $sender_email          = $getMessage->first()->messageSender->email;
    $recipient       = User::where('id', $recipient_id)->first()->name;


    $data =  [
                'id'           => $message_id,
                'date'         => $date,
                'sender'       => $sender,
                'subject'      => $subject,
                'message'      => $message,
                'user_id'      => $user_id,
                'sender_id'    => $sender_id,
                'recipient'    => $recipient,
                'recipient_id' => $recipient_id,
                'sender_email' => $sender_email,  
             ];

    return $data;
}
```

If I will click to read link then not opened needed view with message and not given errors. Only have redirect to back or to current route. Why I can not return needed view and redirected?

#### Downloads

You can see my files [here](http://mahorat.org/download.rar)

Comment: Could you inspect your link and show what is inside `href` attribute?

Comment: `http://study.loc/inbox/read/21`

Comment: `{{ route('read', ['id'=>$message->id]) }}`

Comment: Not work and again redirected

Comment: I create a site with two themes. In the first theme, everything works as it should, but in the current theme it does not work. And so all the same code.

Comment: But if I copy message link and paste to URL needed result returned

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to:

```
{{ route('read', ['id' => $message->id]) }}
```

And make sure you're authenticated.

Comment: So, I assume (actually, not familiar with laravel, but it should look smth similar to like it is done in another frameworks): there is blocker inside your code. I mean that if you're getting redirected to (i think) index page - there is some kind of acl that is blocking request processing from not authenticated users. Possibly, you'll need to look into acl's config and move you read route out of the secured area.

Comment: It's interesting that this code works on the first template but does not work on the second template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{ action('InboxController@read', $message_id) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You pass the href atrr a wrong URL. calling route with a name just render in view as full URL. And the way you do it, it renders as `/read/{id?}/id`.

For passing id via URL you can do it in two ways:

## Method one: calling route name

You can pass the id as this code below:

```
<a href="{{ route('read', ['id'=>$message->id]) }}">
<div class="letter-icon-title text-default">{{$message->messageSender->name}}</div>
```

## Method 2:typing URl

Or you just write the URL and pass it in URL way:

```
<a href="url('inbox/read'.'/'.{{$message->id}})">
    <div class="letter-icon-title text-default">{{$message->messageSender->name}}</div>
</a>
```

**Read this post below:** It refrences this post: [How to Pass Id in Laravel URL Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076237/how-to-pass-id-in-laravel-url-parameter)

```
{{ url('/inbox/read/', [$message->id]) }}
```

But it's a bad idea to use relative paths, because if you'll want to change URL scheme, you will need to manually find tens or hundreds links in your views and controllers and change them manually. In this case you'll definitely forget to change some of them and some pages of your app will be broken.

A good practice is to use links to route:

```
{{ route('name.route', ['id' => $message->id]) }}
```

Or links to action:

```
{{ action('MyController@show', $message->id) }}
```

Comment: @MaxNet Sry I was made a mistake. you have prefix so before 'read' you should add the 'index'. check the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

try `<a href="{{ url('inbox/read'). '/' .$message->id }}">`

Comment: While this might answer the question, some explanation of why it solves the question would be helpful.