# Passing a user id in a url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I'm making a Laravel web application, in this application, I have an Account Settings page. On this page, I want to display all the orders the user has made. In order to do this, I have to get the User id from the URL.

I tried passing the User id thru the URL by putting the Auth::user()->id in the route that leads to the page. however, this is giving me a 404 not found error.

This is the link that should pass the ID in the URL.

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('account/{{ Auth::user()->id }}') }}">
 {{ __('Account Settings') }}
 </a>
```

I also tried to change my web.php file but that's also not giving any result.

I really would appreciate some help with my problem since I've been stuck on this all day.

Comment: What have you defined in your routes file? could you share what you've added to the web.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass Id in Laravel URL Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076237/how-to-pass-id-in-laravel-url-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Laravel route helper. the route would work only for **NAMED ROUTE**,
for example:

```
Route::get('account/{userId}', 'AccountController@show')->name('account');
```

Then, your could should be:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('account', ['userId' => Auth::id()]) }}">
 {{ __('Account Settings') }}
</a>
```

Comment: Or on the href you can do this if you have only one parameter: {{route(‘account ’, Auth::id())}}